# Rails pass a form parameter to determine if a validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to selectively enforce validations on a model. I want the model to enforce them when data is entered from users, but when running files in I want to ignore the validations sometimes. I came up with the less then intelligent method of setting a boolean to TRUE when adding from the web user. Seemed great until I need to update from the file and now I basically have to switch the boolean on all the records. Here is some of my code:

```
class Identity < ActiveRecord::Base

   validate :validate_spouse_age, :if => "web_add?"
   validates :ssn, length: { is: 9 }

   def validate_spouse_age
      if (relationship == "S" || relationship == "DP") && !dob.nil? && web_add? && age<16
      errors.add(:dob, :spouse_under_age)
    end
    true
   end
end
```

So on the web form I just add a hidden_fiedl setting 'web_add' to true and the validation runs and that gets saved to the record. But now when I want to run the following I have to set the boolean back to false or the validation will still run.

```
identity.web_add=false #to allow it to be updated without validation fails
identity.update_attributes!(
    namefirst:          line.FIRST_NAME,
    namelast:           line.LAST_NAME
    )
```

I'm sure there is a smarter way to do this. Why I'm not just ignoring the validation completely is there are some validations that I want to run regardless of the data source. For example, the SSN needs to be there or it should fail out.

Any help would be more then appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can skip the entire 'web_add' boolean and use the `update_attribute` method in your non-web method. You will need to update each attribute individually, but it will skip the validations and commit the changes to the database. You could implement something like:

```
instance.update_attribute(name, value)
```

in your case

```
identity.update_attribute(:namefirst, line.FIRST_NAME)
identity.update_attribute(:namelast, line.LAST_NAME)
```

When a web user submits a form, the validations will run normally. When you run the `update_attribute` method, the validations will be skipped.

Here's a list of all the methods available to [skip activerecord validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#skipping-validations):

```
decrement!
decrement_counter
increment!
increment_counter
toggle!
touch
update_all
update_attribute
update_column
update_counters
```